Propagate exception outside of a Kubeflow component to stop a VertexAI pipeline
In short, VertexAI pipelines are not stopping when an exception is thrown inside a function that is inside an ephemeral_component
An example pipeline, with this stack trace in the logs
2024-04-09 14:10:34.753 BST
  File "/tmp/tmp.c37YCfzDVS/ephemeral_component.py", line 109, in train_classifier
2024-04-09 14:10:34.753 BST
    train_df = preprocess_dataset_sequence(
2024-04-09 14:10:34.753 BST
  File "/pytorch_gpu/src/processes.py", line 530, in preprocess_dataset_sequence
2024-04-09 14:10:34.753 BST
    raise NotImplementedError("Debug raising exception to check if VertexAI stops pipeline.")
2024-04-09 14:10:34.753 BST
NotImplementedError: Debug raising exception to check if VertexAI stops pipeline.

remains in state "Running" indefinitely
An exception thrown just inside the train_classifier component stops the pipeline.
An exception thrown just inside any function called by train_classifier does not stop the pipeline
Is there a proper way to handle exceptions in Kubeflow components?
Minimal code:
@component(
    base_image=os.environ["PYTORCH_GPU_IMAGE_URI"],
)
def train_classifier():
    from src.processes import debug_throw
    
    debug_throw()


def debug_throw():
    raise NotImplementedError("Debug raising exception to check if VertexAI stops pipeline.")

EDIT: I just checked and it seems the VertexAI cost is negligible after the component errors out (3cents for days running), so this may be just a display issue in VertexAI pipelines
